# Best way to partial update nested object data in mongodb in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have searched many questions on nested objects, but all I found where related to array[s].

I am looking for a updating simple nested object in mongoose.
Once created a document, I want to partially update basicDetails and agentDetail object.

Example schema :

```
    var applicationSchema = new Schema({
      title:  String,
      author: String,
      basicDetails:{
        appId:Number,
        fname:String,
        mname:String,
        lname:String
      },
      agentDetails:{
        agentName:String,
        bankName:String,
        bankCode:Number,
        agentCode:Number
      }
      comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
      createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    })
```

I Want to update only `fname` and last name from `basicDetails`,`title`, `bankName` and `agentCode` from `agentDetails`.
    Request is :

```
    {
      title:Update,
      basicDetails:{
        fname:Neeraj,
        lname:singh
      },
      agentDetails:{
        bankName:String,
        agentCode:Number
      }
    }
```

There is no document for the same that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { // match your document }
   { $set: { "basicDetails.fname": newName, "agentDetails.title": newTitle } }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your update but dot notation is not working to update nested array of object fields level. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which array are you trying to update ? Both the fields you started aren't one.

Comment: {
      "title":"Update",
      "basicDetails":{
        "fname":"Neeraj",
        "lname":"singh",
        "familyHealthDetails":[{ 
   "familyMember":"father",
   "status":"live"
  },
  { 
   "familyMember":"brother",
   "status":"live"
  }]
      },
      "agentDetails":{
        "bankName":"String",
        "agentCode":"Number"
      }
    } 
    want to update family Member other instead of father